# How to change the header color of csv in java using ICsvBeanWriter

Tags: java, rest, csv

I am using `ICsvBeanWriter` to generate the CSV file over the REST API, my code looks like

```
// uses the Super CSV API to generate CSV data from the model data
    ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(),
    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

    String[] header = { "Title", "Description", "Author", "Publisher",
                    "isbn", "PublishedDate", "Price" };             

    csvWriter.writeHeader(header);
```

I want to set the header color to some different color rather than the default one. Please tell me how i can do this?

Answer (score 3):

As per definition, [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is comma-separated values stored as plain text. It's a plain text file after all. So no, there is no way of adding colour via Java nor via any editor.

Answer (score 0):

There are no colors in CSV.

The CSV is a textual, data-only format that does not allow any styling information.